# set Rotation to dialog in android

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-animation

Hi i want to set dialog Rotation in degree like this image
[image]

for that i try to set rotation from custom layout in and set rotation to them but 
when i do that my dialog has been cropped like this image
so can anyone help me about this problem?
[image]

my custom layout for dialog:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/propel_shape"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/base_popup_layout"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
>

</LinearLayout>
```

my code:

```
baseLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.base_popup_layout);
baseLayout.setRotation(15);
```

Comment: You should add your existing code to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to extend width and height of the parent of this element

Answer (score 1):

Is there not enough space available for the view? Because I tried running your code, and the shape is rendering as per your requirement, i.e., it is not getting cropped.

[image]

As you can see from the second screenshot, the view boundaries do not change after rotation, so if the view does not have enough space, it will not be displayed properly.

[image]

Comment: hi @Rachit thanks for your answer but a little late .i have question about your second screen shot can you tell me how can show my view like that i mean lines .

Comment: You go to Developer Options and enable "Show Layout Boundaries"